# Link in jekyll menu lead to "404 page not found" erros

Tags: jekyll

I'm new to using jekyll and I think I'm missing something but I can't figure out what.
I built a jekyll page which I compile using 
    bundle exec jekyll build
then I uploaded the contents of the _site folder to the public_html/ folder of my webhoster (name.com).

All menu links, lead to 404 error pages: The menu links generated in the html files point to things like "https://myurl.com/people" while the actual file is called "people.html" so that is why I'm getting a 404. The way I see it, I either need jekyll to generate menu links that include the ".html" file extension, or somehow get my webhoster to serve "people.html" when "people" is requested.

Chris

Comment: What's the `permalink` setting in your config file?

Comment: it is `permalink: /:categories/:title/` but even changing it to `permalink: /:categories/:title/.html` doesn't seem to affect the output that is being created.

Comment: Take a look at .htaccess (if your site uses Apache) or similar for other server software. There are many online sites that can tell you how to configure it to make urls without .html link the proper file anyway, using RewriteEngine, RewriteCond and RewriteRule. It uses a kind of simple regular expression search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

To alter the link structure for *all* of your files, use `permalink` (with proper formatting) in your config file. For example:

```yaml
# _config.yml

# same as `permalink: none`
# note that its ':output_ext' instead of '.html'
permalink: /:categories/:title:output_ext
```

Source: [Official Docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#builtinpermalinkstyles)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. I tried both `permalink: none` and adding `:output_ext` as you write but I'm still getting links without html extension. `<li class="masthead__menu-item"><a href="https://myurl.com/people" >People</a></li>`.

Comment: Can I get the link to your repository (better) or see how your templates are written..?

Comment: I finally figured out the solution. It was the _data/nagivation.yml which had the links as `myurl.com/people` rather than `myurl.com/people.html`. With those updated, the html files generated in the _site/ folder now contain the correct links.